# Mass filtering with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I have serialized a list of objects with protobuf-net.

Theoretically, the .bin file can contain millions of objects.

Let's assume the objects are of a class containing the following:

```
public string EventName;
```

I have to take a query and create a list containing the objects matching the query.
What is the correct way to extract the matching objects from the serialized file using LINQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The protobuf format is a linear sequence of items; any indexing etc you way can only be applies separately. However, `IEnumerable<T>` is available; you might find that:

```
var item = Serializer.DeserializeItems<YourType>(source)
       .First(item => item.Id == id);
```

does the job nicely; this:

- is lazily spooled; each item is yielded individually, so you don't need a glut of memory
- is short-circuited; if the item is found near the start, it'll exit promptly

Or for multiple items:

```
var list = Serializer.DeserializeItems<YourType>(source)
    .Where(item => item.Foo == foo);
```

(add a ToList to te end of the above if you want to buffer the matching items in memory, or use without a ToList if you just want to parse it once in a forwards-only way)

Comment: I think this solution is nice, but the code should be able to extract a number of objects matching the query.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark :). Again. What should I pass as argument for "tag" in DeserializeItems methods?

Comment: I did. What should I pass tag in deserializeItems method?

Comment: @Gilad - `Serializer.ListItemTag` (which is actually just `1`) - and the prefix-style is base-128 (but that is the default anyway)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add some projection over the selected list of elements you should try a library of mine, https://github.com/Scooletz/protobuf-linq. They are available on NuGet as well.
The library lowers overhead of deserialization greatly. In some cases it can drop to 50% of the original query.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't one. In order to use LINQ, your object must implement either `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`. Unless there is a LINQ provider that can provide an `IQueryable<T>` interface into your .bin file, you'll either have to:

- Deserialize the file into memory and use LINQ-to-objects `IEnumerable<T>`
- Write your LINQ provider that can provide an `IQueryable<T>` (and this is likely the only practical option if your file is HUGE) that can process the file without loading the whole thing.

Comment: A good job that DeserializeItems provides an `IEnumerable<T>` API, then

Comment: @Marc: It would appear so! I had assumed that deserialization would load the entire file into memory. Evidently I was wrong on that.

Comment: it will lazily spool them (`yield return`) from the stream - ideal for processing large data volumes

Answer (score 0):

protobuf can give you the contents of the files as a streaming `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can easily do that. Unfortunately I do not know how the method is called but it is easy to find in the docs.

Comment: @Marc how should I serialize items to use DeserializeItems? Do you have a quick example anywhere? I'm stuck trying to do just this in V2.